# Could not transfer artifacts from/to central maven repo when using Spring Framework Cloud

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, spring-cloud

I am trying to create a maven project using Spring Framework Cloud. 
I defined pom.xml file as below

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <!-- Stand-alone RESTFul application for testing only -->
        <start-class>io.pivotal.microservices.services.Main</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Data common components -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Testing starter -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Data JPA Repository support -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- In-memory database for testing/demos -->
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Eureka service registration -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When trying to build maven getting error for all dependencies as

Could not transfer artifacts from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - Failure to transfer org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be     reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
>   org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to
>   transfer org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:
>      4.2.6.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of central has elapsed or updates are      forced.
>   Original error: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
>   at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
>   at

When I go to the location, I can clearly see the Jar files are present in that location.
Is there something else I need to add to my pom.xml?

Comment: Most likely you're behind a corporate proxy and maven hasn't been configured for it.

Comment: There is no such proxy setting. Also, If I override the default version with some other version, it successfully downloads

Comment: Default version of what?

Comment: Have you run Maven on command line or from within Eclipse? If in eclipse please try from plain command line...Apart from that which version of Maven are you using? If this does not help. Delete the directory `$HOME/.m2/repository/org/springframework` and retry...

Comment: @11thdimension - I am using Brixton.RELEASE which by default looks for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE. But if I override version as <version>1.3.6.RELEASE<\version> it downloads successfully. Same for other dependency as well

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using STS. I tried deleting the .m2 repository, but still facing the issue

Comment: It's strange, if it's working for one version and not working for a specific version. I tried your pom and it's working for me, that means there's nothing wrong with POM itself. Try running with `-X or --debug` may be that will give more clues.

Comment: Actually, I switched from STS to eclipse and surprisingly same pom.xml is working fine. It's a mystery how this could be IDE dependent. And that too when STS is built over Eclipse itself. I am clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the same pom.xml inEclipse IDE and surprisingly it worked there as it is.

To make it work on STS, I added following properties

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>io.pivotal.microservices.services.Main</start-class>
        <spring-cloud.version>Brixton.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

Refer [Unable to download/import package org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765370/unable-to-download-import-package-org-springframework-cloud-config-server-enable)

This worked for me, though I am still curious about the difference.

Answer (score 6):

Try force refreshing your dependencies. Specifying `-U` does that

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Edit:
You can purge your local release dependencies and to the normal `mvn clean install` afterwards:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

There is not way to force the release dependencies to be pulled, the `-U` only works with snapshot dependencies

Comment: Thanks, but this was the first thing I tried doing. Unfortunately, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on my project and this is what worked for me.

First of all, go to your `pom.xml` and find your spring-parent version. Then
go to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/springframework/spring-parent and check if your same **springframework** version exists, if not change your **springframework** version to an existing one.