# EnableConfigServer cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, git, eclipse, spring-boot, config

I want to connect my spring cloud config  server by adding @EnableConfigServer but getting error that EnableConfigServer cannot be resolved to a type. Already check the application.properties, name, git repository path and i also already try to clean the project still gettin same error.I cant view localhost:8888/limits-service/default.Please help me

This my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.samazlan.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-cloud-config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45768167/6309), to clean your local .m2 maven cache.

(rename it, to force maven to re-create a new m2 folder).
See if the dependencies are imported then.

Comment: @samazlan simply rename the ~/.m2 folder (see https://mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/). Then relaunch a maven build.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the problem was resolved after changing the starter dependency
from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-**starter-config**</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-**config-server**</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, incredible to me that official documentation uses @EnableConfigServer and lists the dependency "spring-cloud-starter-config". Solved my problem but I am very worried if this is how poorly Spring is maintained